# Can I write "nonsensual data" for data that makes no sense?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

I am worried that "nonsensual data" might come across as data that does not have a lot of erotic vibe....

Comment: Like the opposite of *consensual data*?

Comment: No, as in "making no sense".

Comment: You could just use ***nonsense*** adjectivally. There are hundreds of written instances of [*nonsense data*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nonsense+data%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books.

Comment: No, you can't use *nonsense* adjectivally (that would be *nonsensical*), but you can use *nonsense* as an attributive noun.

Comment: I read "nonsensual data" as "data not perceived by the senses" and thought that we were going to be talking about psychics.

Comment: Sadly (?) most data are rather non-sensual..

Comment: "Oh George, your data is so sensual," she moaned. :-) There must be some geek erotica in there somewhere.

Comment: @Jay: no, apparently George's data was quite the opposite...

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Absolutely not!

The term you're looking for is *nonsensical*. As in "without sense".

Thanks for the chuckle, haha!

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks, that's the word! In my head, I thought "nonsense"->"nonsensual", but it did not feel quite right... :-)

Comment: That would make sense logically, and if we didn't already have the word "sensual" in the English language that's what it would probably be instead. But yeah, nonsense data is nonsensical and boring old data that doesn't kiss on the first date is nonsensual!

Comment: Well, maybe I should throw away my nonsensical data (since it does not make sense anyway) and go get some sensual data..

Comment: Joined this just to upvote this question and answer.

Comment: @aitchnyu welcome to the site!

Comment: Yeah, nonsensical. As a native speaker can tell what you meant by context and similarity. I would have gotten a good laugh out of it though.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the term "nonsensual data", it just means something else: data not derived from the human senses.

Answer (score 14):

#### **non·sen·si·cal**

ˌnänˈsensək(ə)l/
adjective
1. having no meaning; making no sense.
*"a nonsensical argument"*
synonyms:   **meaningless, senseless, illogical**
*"her nonsensical way of talking"*

Comment: Welcome to ELL :-). Can you please edit your post to add a reference to a dictionary entry? It's a good answer, if it had a reference, I would certainly upvote it ;-)

Comment: I feel bad that the accepted answer also has no reference, but it gets 37 votes while giving less information than this answer.

Comment: @justhalf: the accepted answer does not seem to literally _quote_ from a non-disclosed source. It's that unattributed quoting that is the problem - some would call that plagiarism.

Comment: @oerkelens: Can you advice me on this? The definition seems to be taken from Google Define by searching "nonsensical" in Google. Google doesn't seem to list the source, though.

Comment: @justhalf - if you quote a definition from Google Define, then simply say as much. Don't leave the community wondering what dictionary you got your definition from.

Comment: @J.R.: Can we edit the answer to include that it's from Google Define? It seems exactly the same, and this is the first answer for Jean Desjardins.

Comment: @justhalf - Do you get the same synonyms listed there? Anyhow, we could edit it, but I think it would be best to let the OP come back and edit it themselves, based on these comments. If it's not edited after a few days, then an edit from a member would be prudent.

Comment: @J.R.: It's exactly the same, even the IPA and the examples. But I agree it's best to wait for OP to edit. It's better if OP can give more explanation also why *nonsensical* will be a better choice than *nonsensual* =)

Answer (score 6):

It is also entirely correct to say "nonsense data." In some cases it's actually better. If you were trying to produce data that was nonsense to feed into a program for testing purposes, I would expect it to just be called "nonsense data."

Comment: I won't comment on the grammar of "feeding a program nonsense data to see what happens" , but I can concur that this is a very common usage in engineering in the U.S.

Answer (score 4):

As a developer, I would strongly recommend the term ***contrived*** for describing data that is without semantic value (e.g. 'lorem ipsum' text). To say something is ***contrived*** specifically conveys that it was created intentionally or artificially, which would perfectly explain the existence of data that is otherwise meaningless.